# lua tonumber strange behavor

Tags: lua

When i use tonumber(), the value changes to nil?

```
   luxValue = otherdevices['Lux Woonkamer']
   print("Lux: " .. luxValue)
```

Lux: 55

```
luxValue = otherdevices['Lux Woonkamer']--still value 55
print("Lux: " .. tonumber(luxValue))
```

attempt to concatenate a nil value

```
luxValue = tostring(otherdevices['Lux Woonkamer'])--still value 55
print("Lux: " .. tonumber(luxValue))
```

attempt to concatenate a nil value

Can someone explain?

Comment: Are you sure that `luxValue` is *exactly* `"55"` and that there are no trailing/leading space characters or any other invisible marks?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, not 100% sure.
Is there a way to check if there are any trailing/leading space characters or any other invisible marks?

Comment: ahh, found the problem! I added: 
luxValue = luxValue:gsub("[^%w ]", "") and it works propely. Thanks again.

Comment: I recommend printing things like `print("Value: (" .. luxValue .. ")")` or similar, because you'll see a noticeable gap between the `(` and the number!

Comment: Ahh, thanks! I will use that next time.